# how to secure app.config, while it is intended to be used on several machines?

Tags: c#, app-config

I want to create an application that connects to a central remote database, and this application is intended to be given to several users to use on their computer, in a local network. the main challenge for us is to hide connection string from the users, in order to prevent potentially malicious uses.
thus far i've found that i must use `RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider` class, described at [there](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.rsaprotectedconfigurationprovider.aspx) to encrypt `app.config`, and to decrypt it. but i can't figure out how can i give the needed RSA keys to clients? and how all this prevents crackers from finding the key and using it to decrypt `app.config`?

thanx everyone ;)

Comment: If you find a way to give the RSA keys to the clients, how will you ensure that they won't find some way of using those to decrypt the app.config? Also, what is sensitive in your connection string that you don't want them to see?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/781658/web-config-encryption-using-rsaprotectedconfigurationprovider-bad-data-error

Comment: @BrianWarshaw AFAIK if they find find the connection string, potentially they can write apps to connect to our database and do bad things.

Comment: @BrianWarshaw again AFAIK windows itself stores some private keys for users, in a safe place. i just thought that maybe we can store our key in that place too; because we have admin privileges and they don't.

Comment: @ken2k i want all of the importing process to be automated; can we do it with this solution? also how much is it compatible with c#? thanx ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> the main challenge for us is to hide connection string from the users

You can't let users have client applications that connect directly to the database, and expect to be able to hide the connection string. This can't be done.

If the connection string must stay secret, store it on the server and let client applications connect to a web service, instead of directly to the database.

Comment: i've heard this solution as an alternative, but we wanted to avoid complexities as far as we could. could you please update your answer, with more info on why our solution can't be safe? is it due to memory dumping vulnerability or something else? thanx ;)

Comment: When your connection is stored on a user's machine, it means it will be dectypted there. Once it is stored decrypted in memory, it can be read. A simple memory dump of the process is enough to reveal this connection string.

Comment: doesn't `System.Security.SecureString` help us?

Comment: [Unfortunately not](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1922313/using-securestring-for-a-sql-connection).

Comment: If you don't want your users having access to a database, then don't give it to them, even if you're trying to give it to them via a client. If you don't want the complexity of a web service, then consider giving all of the necessary users the required access to the database and having them authenticate in your client with their own credentials. If that sounds like a hassle, see Steven's answer. A web service will give you the benefit of access control outside of the DB.

Answer (score 4):

If you read through the [web farm secenarios](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650304.aspx#paght000006_webfarmscenarios) of the [How To: Encrypt Configuration Sections in ASP.NET 2.0 Using RSA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650304.aspx) article on MSDN, you will see how to create a key and extract the private and public keys from it in order to install the public key on different machines.

Summary:

1. Create a custom key:

   ```
   aspnet_regiis -pc "CustomKeys" -exp
   ```
2. Add a `configProtectedData` section to the config file, to use the custom key
3. Encrypt the wanted sections
4. Export the key:

   ```
   aspnet_regiis -px "CustomKeys" "C:\CustomKeys.xml" -pri
   ```
5. Copy and import the key in the other machines:

   ```
   aspnet_regiis -pi "CustomKeys" "C:\CustomKeys.xml"
   ```

Comment: i saw this solution, but dismissed it. can i somehow automate the 5th step? i want it to be done without my presence, and i can't trust the admin who installs it to be able to do this without err.

Comment: also is it completely compatible with c#?

Comment: @sazary - Nothing to do with C#, but yes, the framework supports this fully. As for automating the 5th step - sure. Batch files, PowerShell scripts or whatever.

Comment: so it could not be done from inside the c# code, am i right? i need to write a separated batch file and then invoke it from inside c# code, right?

Comment: @sazary - Sure, you could do it that way. The [`Process`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx) class will help if you go that way.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same problem these days and found another solution, maybe is not very elegant but it worked for me.
I used an AES algorithm to encrypt the connection string with a key defined by me, and replaced the resulting string in the config file.
Then I added a decrypting function with the same key in my app and used it on the get connectionstring method, something like this:

```
public string myConnectionString {
    get {
        return ((new Cypher().Decrypt(this["myConnectionString"].ToString())));
    }
}
```

The main disadvantage is that these changes may be overriden when compiling, so it's better to do it when you app is ready.
I used the methods for encrypting/decrypting that I found here: 
[AES Encryption Decryption (Cryptography) Tutorial with example in ASP.Net using C# and VB.Net](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/AES-Encryption-Decryption-Cryptography-Tutorial-with-example-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx)